# 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'to_json'

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, keras, keras-2

I'm unable to save the model trained using KerasRegressor wrapper...

```
model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, epochs=1, batch_size=10, verbose=1)
model.fit(X,Y)

model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)
    model.save_weights("model.h5", overwrite=True)
    logger.info("Saved model to disk")
```

Here's my import:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.models import model_from_json

# multi gpu
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.layers.core import Lambda
from keras.layers.merge import Concatenate
```

And the error I got is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train-model.py", line 175, in <module>
  File "train-model.py", line 114, in main
    model.save_weights("model.h5", overwrite=True)
AttributeError: 'KerasRegressor' object has no attribute 'to_json'
```

I build the model in using a function that returns a model:

```
def base_model():
    global N, M

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, input_dim=M, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(128, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal', activation='linear'))

    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='rmsprop')

    # model = to_multi_gpu(model)

    return model
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You first need to access the under lying model over which the kerasregressor wrapper is used, and then call save on it. Use `model.model.tojson()` and `model.model.save_weights()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to use:
`model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=base_model, epochs=1, batch_size=10, verbose=1)`
`model.fit(X,Y)`
`def save_model_to_json(my_model):`
   `json_model = my_model.model.to_json()`
   `with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:`
      `json_file.write(json_model)`
   `my_model.model.save_weights("model.h5")`
`save_model_to_json(model)`
`#two files will be generated, model.json, which is your model and model.h5 which is #the file that has the weights of your model`\